# Error "best candidate" while doing yum update

Tags: linux, unix, redhat, yum

How to resolve below error while doing `sudo yum update`

```
#sudo yum update
Error:
 Problem 1: cannot install the best update candidate for package netdata-1.30.1-2.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libjson-c.so.4(JSONC_0.14)(64bit) needed by netdata-1.37.1-1.el8.x86_64
 Problem 2: package netdata-1.30.1-2.el8.x86_64 requires netdata-conf = 1.30.1-2.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both netdata-conf-1.37.1-1.el8.noarch and netdata-conf-1.30.1-2.el8.noarch
  - problem with installed package netdata-1.30.1-2.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package netdata-conf-1.30.1-2.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides libjson-c.so.4(JSONC_0.14)(64bit) needed by netdata-1.36.1-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libjson-c.so.4(JSONC_0.14)(64bit) needed by netdata-1.37.1-1.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean the cache and then update.

```
# sudo yum clean all
# sudo yum check
# sudo yum check-update
# sudo yum update
```

If there is still a problem then try with `sudo yum update --nobest` command.

Set `best=False` in `/etc/yum.conf` file to disable the "install best candidate" feature.

**Note:** This feature is disabled by default.

- Refer: https://cloudlinux.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408411384722-Yum-cannot-install-the-best-update-candidate-for-package-on-server-with-Imunify360